# log4net accessing context properties from custom appender

Tags: c#, azure, log4net, azure-functions

I am using log4net with a custom appender that logs to Azure Storage Tables, and am having issues accessing `log4net.GlobalContext` properties from within my Appender. I am logging from inside an Azure Function.

The appending is pretty straight forward and simple and works fine, but I would like to add a couple custom properties - one of which is an InvocationId and only accessible from the Azure Functions, so i would like to know the best way to achieve this.

Any idea what I'm missing?

**Appender**

```
protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
{
  _tableCtx.Log(new LogEntry
                {
                  Timestamp = loggingEvent.TimeStamp,
                  Message = loggingEvent.RenderedMessage,
                  Level = loggingEvent.Level.Name,
                  // properties is always empty
                  InvocationId = loggingEvent.Properties["InvocationId"],
                  PartitionKey = loggingEvent.LoggerName,
                 });
}
```

**Azure Function**

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MyFunction([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")]HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
{

  log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["InvocationId"] = context.InvocationId;
  using (var config = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyFunc.logging.config"))
  {
      log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(config);
  }

   var log = LogManager.GetLogger(context.FunctionName);
}
```

Comment: It looks like it may be easier to do this kind of work in the appender xml file? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775568/add-a-custom-property-to-a-loggingeventdata-programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this, which was way simpler than i thought it would be.

```
log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["InvocationId"].ToString()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
loggingEvent.GetProperties()["InvocationId"]
```

or

```
loggingEvent.LookupProperty("InvocationId")
```

See [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/P_log4net_Core_LoggingEvent_Properties.htm) for more details

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the Property after you initialize log4net:

```
  using (var config = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyFunc.logging.config"))
  {
      log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(config);
  }

  var log = LogManager.GetLogger(context.FunctionName);

  log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["InvocationId"] = context.InvocationId;
```

You also only have to initialize log4net when it is not yet initialized. Doing it on every call is not very efficient.